# Jekyll subfolders with different output

Tags: jekyll

In jekyll, i am using collections in order to define the contents of a site. I organised it like this:

```
site
    _contents
        jobs               
   _solutions
```

I want the files in solutions to generate pages, but not the ones in jobs. So i configured the collections like so:

```
collections:
  contents:
    output: false
  solutions:
    output: true
```

My boss, however, wants me to organise the site like so:

```
site
    _contents
        jobs
        solutions
```

i tried to make this work by configuring like this:

```
collections:
  contents:
    output: false
    solutions:
      output: true
```

this does not work. Is what i'm trying to do possible?

// EDIT: another alternative in config.yml could be...

```
collections:
  contents/jobs:
    output: false
  content/solutions:
    output: true
```

Comment: You cannot do this. The output setup is the collection and cannot be applied to one path in a collection.

Comment: Ive edited the question, would this other idea work? Having each directory within contents be its own collection?

Comment: Or rather, i know it does not work as described here, but is it possible to do it some other way?

Comment: The question is why a single collection ? You can use two collections, jobs and solutions.

Comment: honestly, i don't know. The boss said so is the closest thing to a real answer.

Comment: but thanks for the help, ill just do this the way it works. Better a working site that is a tad different then a not working site.

Comment: Good luck with the boss

Comment: thanks. he's cool, so i'm lucky.